# Java Error Exception to be thrown, but nothing was thrown

Tags: java

Tengo una duda al pasar un test en Java y un throw ProductException el cual no me deja avanzar con la tarea. Adjunto una foto del diagrama por si es necesario facilitar mas codigo.

```
public abstract class PhysicalProduct extends Product implements Stockable {
    private int stock;
    Campaign campaign;
    ProductException productException;
    Book book;

    // Constructor por defecto clase Product
    public PhysicalProduct() throws ProductException {
        super();
    }

    // Constructor parametrizado con atributos heredados.
    public PhysicalProduct(String name, int publicationYear, String description, double price, int stock) throws ProductException {
        setName(name);
        setPublicationYear(publicationYear);
        setDescription(description);
        setPrice(price);
        setStock(stock);
    }

    // Método que da error:
    public void activePromotion(Promotion promotion) throws ProductException {
        if (campaign == Campaign.BOOK_DAY || campaign == Campaign.CHRISTMAS) {
            setPromotion(promotion);
        } else if( campaign == Campaign.SUMMER || campaign == Campaign.BLACK_FRIDAY) {
            throw new ProductException(MSG_ERR_PROMOTION_NOT_ALLOWED);
        }
    }
```

Este es el test que no consigo pasar por el siguiente error:

*Exception to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.*

```
    @Test
    @Order(3)
    void testActivePromotion() {

        assertNull(book.getPromotion());

        Promotion promotion1 = new Promotion(20, Campaign.SUMMER, 7);
        Promotion promotion2 = new Promotion(15, Campaign.CHRISTMAS, 5);

        try{

            Exception ex = assertThrows(Exception.class, () ->  book.activePromotion(promotion1));
            assertEquals(ProductException.MSG_ERR_PROMOTION_NOT_ALLOWED, ex.getMessage());

            book.activePromotion(promotion2);
            assertEquals(promotion2, book.getPromotion());

            book.setPromotion(null);
            assertNull(book.getPromotion());

        }catch(ProductException e) {
            fail("testActivePromotion failed");
        }
    }
```

Os adjunto también la clase ProductException donde no debería existir ningún problema:

```
public class ProductException extends Exception{

    public static String MSG_ERR_NAME = "[ERROR] Product's name cannot be longer than 50 characters";
    public static String MSG_ERR_PUBLICATION_YEAR = "[ERROR] Product's publicationYear cannot be later than current year";
    public static String MSG_ERR_DESCRIPTION = "[ERROR] Product's description cannot be longer than 250 characters";
    public static String MSG_ERR_NEGATIVE = "[ERROR] Product's price cannot be negative";
    public static String MSG_ERR_PARAMETER_INCORRECT = "[ERROR] parameter is not the correct format";
    public static String MSG_ERR_PROMOTION_NOT_ALLOWED = "[ERROR] Product's promotion are not allowed";


    public ProductException() {
        super();
    }

    public ProductException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

La clase Book ya que el test es a partir de un objeto Book:

```
public class Book extends PhysicalProduct{

    private int pages = 1;
    private String isbn = "9780000000000";
    ProductException productException;
    public Promotion promotion;

    public Book() throws ProductException{
    }

    public Book(String name, int publicationYear, String description, double price, int stock, int pages) throws ProductException {
        setName(name);
        setPublicationYear(publicationYear);
        setDescription(description);
        setPrice(price);
        setStock(stock);
        setPages(pages);

    }

    public Book(String name, int publicationYear, String description, double price, int stock, int pages, String isbn) throws Exception {
        setName(name);
        setPublicationYear(publicationYear);
        setDescription(description);
        setPrice(price);
        setStock(stock);
        setPages(pages);
        setIsbn(isbn);
    }
```

Y la superclase Product que es donde se encuentra el método principal getPromotion y setPromotion:

```
public abstract class Product {
    private static int referenceId  = 15000;
    private int reference;
    private String name;
    private int publicationYear;
    private String description;
    private double price;
    private VAT percentage = VAT.STANDARD;
    ProductException productException;
    public Promotion promotion;
    private int sales = 0;


    public Product() throws ProductException {
        this("Lorem Ipsum", 2011, "lorem ipsum description", 7.50 );
    }

    public Product(String name, int publicationYear, String description, double price) throws ProductException {
        setName(name);
        setPublicationYear(publicationYear);
        setDescription(description);
        setPrice(price);
        createReference();
    }

    public Promotion getPromotion() {return promotion;}


    protected Promotion setPromotion(Promotion promotion) {
        this.promotion = promotion;
        return promotion;
    }
```

Muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la definición del método utilizas una comparación así: `campaign == Campaign.SUMMER || campaign == Campaign.BLACK_FRIDAY`, pero ese `campaign` hace referencia al `campaign` de la clase, no al de la `promotion` que le pasas al método!! Deberías hacer las comparaciones con `promotion.getCampaign()`

Comment: Revisa bien las implementaciones de tus clases... no es correcto que tengas un objeto de tipo `promotion` y un objeto de tipo `campaign` cuando en teoría `campaign` pertenece a `promotion` y no a `physicalproduct`

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias!! disculpa estoy un poco verde en java..